# Intellij: Format multiline string as a Javadoc comment

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Is there a hot key to format a multiline string as a Javadoc comment?

> This is a comment
>
> I want to format it as a comment
>
> Please format me

to

```
/**
 * This is a comment
 * I want to format it as a comment
 * Please format me
 */
```

cmd + / only formats it as a `//` comment

**Edit**
Have no idea why this is getting downvoted with no comments or answers, but I will update it:

I have a 1300 line file with many strings in them, all of which are multi lined. I need to take these multi line strings, none of which are Javadoc comments, and make them javadoc comments. I **do not want to use //** I **very specifically want the Java standard Javadoc comments** that are in the form of

```
/**
 * 
 */
```

I am trying to avoid going over 1300 lines and manually adding the comment strings.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to create Javadoc in IntelliJ IDEA is to type the opening block comment `/**`, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. The rest of code will be generated by IDEA.

Javadoc `/**...*/` differs from the regular comment block `/*...*/` in the way that is also includes some additional information like `@param`, `@return`, `@see` etc and some tags like `{@link URL}` for creating HTML from running Javadoc.

If you want to convert some existing comment block to Javadoc, you can do it in such way:

1. Add one more asterisk `*` to make the comment a Javadoc.
2. Put caret somewhere within a class, method, function, or field, which should be documented and press <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to invoke [Find Action](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/navigating-to-action.html) command.
3. Type `fix doc comment` in the input field and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
4. The missing documentation stub with the corresponding tags will be added.

You can also fix your Javadoc is this way when for example a method signature has been changed, with IDEA's quick fix suggestions.

Hope this will help you. Read more [Creating Documentation Comments](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/creating-documentation-comments.html).